# Get given timezone timestamp

Tags: go

I am playing around with timezone and noticed something wierd.

I am currently in the BST timezone which is an hour ahead of GMT.

```
        now := time.Now()
        location, _ := time.LoadLocation("Atlantic/Cape_Verde")
        timeAtZone := now.In(location)
        fmt.Println(timeAtZone)
        timestamp = timeAtZone.Unix()
        fmt.Println(timestamp)
        fmt.Println(now.Add(-time.Hour).UTC().Unix())
        fmt.Println(now.UTC().Unix())
```

You will notice that the timestamp is that of BST my current timezone.

How do I get the timestamp of GMT???

http://play.golang.org/p/oq0IRYa0h7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unix time is absolute. There is no "BST Unix time." There is no "Atlantic/Cape_Verde" Unix time." There is only Unix time. It is the number of seconds since a specific moment ([00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, not counting leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).

Time zones are related to the *representation* of time, not time itself. It is the same moment for you as it is for me, wherever we are in the world (leaving Einstein aside for the moment). We just happen to call that moment different things. Setting the location on a `*Time` just indicates how you would like to display the time. So if by "timestamp" you mean "string representing the time," you can get the UTC timestamp with `time.Now().UTC().String()`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check your errors, I assume it's telling you there's an issue.

Have you checked: http://golang.org/pkg/time/#LoadLocation

Is your timezone in: $GOROOT/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip?

For me:

```
time.LoadLocation("CDT") // my time zone
time.LoadLocation("CST")
```

Both result in an error.

To get my time zone, I must do:

```
time.LoadLocation("America/Chicago")
```

Make sure f.Timezone is valid.

Comment: Sorry f.timezone was taken from the code.. I have updated it with the right time zone "Atlantic/Cape_Verde"